# HBase in Tomcat attempts to reconnect forever when host is down

Tags: tomcat, hbase

I wrote an HBase connector as below. The purpose of the configuration settings is to fail fast, if the HBase host machine is down, we want to throw an error as soon as possible so that the user don't have to wait forever. If I use the following code as a standalone java program when the host machine is not up, it throws exceptions after several seconds which is what we want.

```java
package mypackage.connector;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTableInterface;

public class Connector {

    public void connectAndGetTable() throws IOException{
        String tableName = "test";
        String hNode = "192.168.56.103";
        // Hbase Configurations
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", hNode);
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        conf.set("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://192.168.56.103:8020/apps/hbase/data");
        conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
        conf.set("hbase.rpc.timeout", "1000");
        conf.set("hbase.client.retries.number", "1");
        conf.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", "100");
        conf.set("zookeeper.recovery.retry", "1");
        conf.set("hbase.client.pause", "100");
        conf.set("hbase.client.operation.timeout", "100");

        // create an hbase connection
        HConnection connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(conf);
        // get table handle from hbase connection
        HTableInterface table = connection.getTable(tableName);
        table.close();
    }
}
```

However, if I put that in Tomcat, and access it like so in a jsp page:

```jsp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Sample JSP Page</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Sample JSP Page</h1>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="mypackage.connector.Connector"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.hadoop.*"%>
<%
Connector connector=new Connector();
connector.connectAndGetTable();
%>
</body></html>
```

When I hit the jsp page, after several seconds it throws the following exceptions which is what we want：

```
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for  after 1 tries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1067)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getTable(HConnectionManager.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getTable(HConnectionManager.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getTable(HConnectionManager.java:735)
    at loblaw.connector.Connector.connectAndGetTable(Connector.java:32)
    at org.apache.jsp.hello_jsp._jspService(hello_jsp.java:77)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    ... 23 more
```

However, after this it tries to reconnect to HBase forever with the following log:

```
2015-06-01 13:24:30 INFO  ClientCnxn:1083 - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 1103ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-06-01 13:24:31 INFO  ClientCnxn:966 - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.56.103/192.168.56.103:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-01 13:24:31 INFO  ClientCnxn:1083 - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 1102ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-06-01 13:24:32 INFO  ClientCnxn:966 - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.56.103/192.168.56.103:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-01 13:24:32 INFO  ClientCnxn:1083 - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 1102ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-06-01 13:24:33 INFO  ClientCnxn:966 - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.56.103/192.168.56.103:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-01 13:24:33 INFO  ClientCnxn:1083 - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 1102ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-06-01 13:24:34 INFO  ClientCnxn:966 - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.56.103/192.168.56.103:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-01 13:24:34 INFO  ClientCnxn:1083 - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 1102ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-06-01 13:24:35 INFO  ClientCnxn:966 - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.56.103/192.168.56.103:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-01 13:24:36 INFO  ClientCnxn:1083 - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 1101ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

This just goes on and on forever. How do I stop this behavior in Tomcat? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding "zookeeper.session.timeout" in hbase-site.xml as mentioned [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Troubleshooting#A8)

Comment: Do you mean to edit that value on the server side? The situation here is that the host machine is not reachable at all. On the client side I already set `zookeeper.session.timeout` to 100ms. Doesn't help in Tomcat.